# extracting particular column using header name in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to learn python and a beginner. I have a tab delimited text file and I would like to extract 2nd column of the file using the header name of the 2nd column. This is my dummy file:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
a   1   2   3
d   4   5   0
f   3   2   1
```

I have done something like this:

```
f = open('test.txt',"r")
header = f.readline()
header = firstline.rstrip("\n").split("\t")
for row in f:
 row = row.rstrip("\n")
 # i cannot figure out what should I do next
```

I want the output to be

```
col2
1
4
3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the index of your column in a variable:

```
f = open("test.txt", "r")
col_index = f.readline().rstrip("\n").split("\t").index("col2")
for row in f:
    print(row.rstrip("\n").split("\t")[col_index])
```